# Jest snapshots not matching - Windows vs Unix/Linux Line Endings

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, eslint, prettier

We have a project developed by multiple developers on multiple operating systems. We have a character limit in our prettier config set to 120 characters. Our windows machines are producing snapshots different than our linux/unix machines.

windows:

```
              <h4
                className="RightPanel__item--heading heading--headingBlocks
subHeading--headingBlocks subHeading--different"
              >
```

whereas on our linux/unix machines the snapshot produces the following line:

```
              <h4
                className="RightPanel__item--heading heading--headingBlocks subHeading--headingBlocks subHeading--different"
              >
```

For the linux/unix snapshot, the code ends right on column 119, whereas windows machines produce a new line before the last couple of attributes.
We use React, Jest for Testing, eslint for linting, Babel for transformation.

### Related Configuration

1. babelrc: transform: { "^.+\.jsx?$": "babel-jest" }
2. eslintrc: "globals": { "jest": true }
3. prettierrc: "printWidth": 120
4. prettierignore: *.snap

### Project

React, Babel, Webpack, vanilla es6+ no typescript project with jest for testing

### Research

We've tried setting the eslint's "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"] to see if the eslint change would update the fix the jest snapshot for windows to no avail. We've ensured the same installed version of jest across machines. Same with prettier and eslint.

Any suggestions on how we might fix this issue so tests don't fail for one OS or the other?

Comment: Are you running prettier over the generated snapshot files?

Comment: No, I'm not actually sure how the 120 character limit actually comes to play here. In our .prettierignore we have *.snap. We don't have a 120 character limit in our eslint config

Comment: Thats weird, and this doesn't happen if you increase the limit to 130 for example?

Comment: It doesn't actually change the snapshot if I increase the character length to 130, or even 160, in my prettierrc. I'm going to take a look at my eslint extends and see if there's a character limit there.

Comment: If thats the case then this might not be a prettier related. Maybe you can narrow the problem down closer to jest itself by (temporarily ofc) throwing out dependencies one by one. This sounds like it could be a jest bug

Comment: I have the same issue, snapshot in my MAC is diff with windows by a break-line. Does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to synchronize something like this across a team is to use EditorConfig. Most code editors support it, either natively or through an extension.

EditorConfig is a universal way to specify editor setting, Line Endings in your case, that is respected by all code editors on all OSes.

https://editorconfig.org

```
# Unix-style newlines with a newline ending every file
[*]
end_of_line = lf
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using snapshot serializer in our project to avoid such issues, it should help in your case too. For html snapshots I recommend [jest-serializer-html](https://github.com/rayrutjes/jest-serializer-html)

Comment: This does not change anything nor answers the OP. jest-serializer makes the snapshot pretty but does not affect line-endings.

In order to output CRLF or LF the test itself has to be in the desired format. You can use crlf in CLI (https://www.npmjs.com/package/crlf) to transform your files prior to running jest.

Comment: @MarionLP The issue here is that line breaks are inserted differently on different operating systems, not that the line breaks are represented with different character sequences.

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same issue where Windows machines were generating snapshots with different line breaks than Macs.

We found out that VS Code was set to LF line break settings on the windows machine and changing to CRLF fixed the issue.

I'd recommend checking line ending settings in your editors and anywhere else earlier in the chain.